# Describing stress in Spanish

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

In Spanish class, I remember learning that "stress" (as in what someone who is coming up on a deadline feels) isn't commonly spoken of in Spanish-speaking countries for cultural reasons, but it can be translated by the "Spanglish" *estrés*. Looking up "stress" in [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=stress) shows it can be translated *estrés*, *tensión*, or *presión*, and looking in the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=estr%C3%A9s) shows *estrés* is actually an accepted word with that meaning.

What is the most common way of saying "stress" in Spanish-speaking countries? And how would other common expressions involving stress be translated, like:

- This is a very **stressful** job.
- I've been really **stressed out** lately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I (Spaniard guy) would say:

- This is a very stressful job *- Éste es un trabajo muy estresante.*
- I've been really stressed out lately. *- He estado muy estresado últimamente.*

Sample usage (veridical): I've got my mom fed up with my "*¡Ay!, ¡No me estreses!*" every time she tells me to clean my room.

Some other approaches may include:

- Es un trabajo con mucha presión (*It's job with a lot of pressure*)
- Trabajo bien bajo presión (*I work well under pressure*... Erm... Unless an English speaking person understands that I function properly at great depths in the ocean, where the water pressure is high)
- Sufro mucha presión en el trabajo (*I'm very pressured at work*) although if someone told me this, I would probably think that the pressure comes from an element non exactly job-related, but more like a nasty boss or something... (this is a very, very subjective detail, though)

Comment: "pesado" (heavy) is commonly used in my experience to explain "stressful" situations. As in `Tuve un día muy pesado.` or `Mi trabajo es muy pesado.`  All variations on the same theme, though.

Answer (score 4):

the most accurate term for that is, as [Borrajax has said](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2081/620), *estresante*, but you can also use other terms like *agobiante* (from [agobio](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=agobio))

As RAE says:

> agobio.
>
> 1. m. Acción y efecto de agobiar.
> 2. m. Sofocación, angustia.

So you can translate those sentences as:

> Este trabajo es muy agobiante
>
> Hoy estoy muy agobiado